# How to save dataframe as shp/geojson in PySpark/Databricks?

Tags: pyspark, databricks, geospatial, geojson, shapefile

I have a DataFrame that has WKT in one of the columns. That column can be transformed to geojson if needed.

Is there a way to save (output to storage) this data as a geojson or shapefile in Databricks/PySpark?

Example of a DataFrame:

| Id | Color | Wkt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Green | POINT (3 7) |
| 2 | Yellow | POLYGON ((30 10, 40 40, 20 40, 10 20, 30 10)) |

The DataFrame can have ~100K rows and more.

I've tried using `Geopandas` library, but it doesn't work:

```
import geopandas as gpd

# df is as PySpark dataframe

# Covert it to Pandas dataframe
pd_df = df.toPandas()
pd_df['geometry']=pd['point_wkt'].apply(wkt.loads)

# Convert it to GeoPandas dataframe
gdf  = gpd.GeoDataFrame(pd, geometry='geometry')

# The following fails:
gdf.to_file(os.path.join(MOUNT_POINT,output_folder,"shapefile.shp"))
```

The error is:

```
Failed to create file /mnt/traces/output_folder/shapefile.shp: No such file or directory
```

The error makes no sense as the folder `/mnt/traces/output_folder/` does exist, and I've successfully saved the PySpark dataframe as CSV to it.

`df.write.csv(os.path.join(MOUNT_POINT,output_folder), sep='\t')`

I'm able to save GeoPandas dataframe to shapefile with the above code when running locally, but not on Spark (Databricks).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Databricks then

```
dbutils.library.installPyPI("geopandas")
dbutils.library.installPyPI("shapely")
dbutils.library.installPyPI("geojsonio")
```

If you are using pyspark then it will be similar to Python Environment

```
pip3 install shapely
pip3 install geopandas
pip3 install geojsonio
```

Before writing to the path please check whether the path is mounted in databricks

```
display(dbutils.fs.ls('/mnt/traces'))
```

Comment: I've tried using GeoPandas, but get a weird error. Can you please take a look at my question again? I've added additional info.

Comment: don't use `dbutils.library.installPyPI`! use `%pip` instead

Comment: @AlexOtt thanks, but that’s not the issue here. I’ve installed Geopandas on cluster level, outside the notebook.

Comment: It was a comment to Subash

Comment: @AlexOtt BTW I took reference from Databricks's public document-https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/8617742580000515/2268731778511343/5915122476030367/latest.html. Also its depends on developer choice based on the workbook or cluster level

Comment: @Alcibiades I believe your original question was how to use the libraries in Pyspark and Databricks. Its recommended not to modify the original ask as it's not in the best interest of other seekers.But since you asked I have modified my answer

Comment: In case if the solution served your purpose please upvote so that others are benefitted as well

Comment: this  notebook requires update: https://docs.databricks.com/libraries/notebooks-python-libraries.html - notice that it was completely removed in DBR 11

Answer (score 0):

If you use dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/traces/output_folder/") you'll see this path:
**dbfs:/mnt/** traces/output_folder/shapefile.shp which takes us to our solution:

***Solution:*** when writing we CAN use **/dbfs/mnt/** for path instead of */mnt/lab/*:

```
gdf.to_file("/dbfs/mnt/traces/output_folder/shapefile.shp")
```

Good luck!